# What is the verb expressing the action of moving some farm animals in a field to let them eat grass or plants?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

The verb "drive an animal" is to force an animal to move. For example, *the shepherd is driving a cow*. It does not mean to make the cow eat.

**What is the common verb expressing the action of moving some farm animals in a field to let them eat grass or plants?**

Comment: Shepherds look after sheep. A cowherd or (UK) cowman looks after cattle. You might drive animals to a different field so that they can graze (eat grass) there.

Comment: You can't say a shepherd drives a cow.  Shepherds look after sheep, not cows.  Driving cattle is the usual expression (for cows/bulls).  Sheep can be shepherded. "To shepherd sheep" means to guide them.  "To herd" animals is also possible, i.e. to move as animals (as a group/herd). You can also "pasture" an animal, which means to move them to an area of grass to allow them to graze.

Comment: @KateBunting A **herdsman** is a non-animal-specific term for a male person who looks after farm animals, and the non-gender-specific **herdsperson** is often seen in job vacancy advertisements these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cows *graze*

And sometimes farm animals are allowed to *pasture*

> ## graze
>
> to (cause animals to) eat grass:
> *The cows were grazing.*
> *The farmer **grazes cattle** on this land in the summer months.*
>  <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/graze)</sub>

> ## pasture
>
> verb transitive
> 3.  to put (cattle, etc.) out to graze in a pasture
> 4.  to graze or feed on (grass, etc.)
>  <sub>[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pasture)</sub>